# write a r function to replace missing value with previous value

Tags: r, missing-data

I try to replace missing value previous value and it works, but I failed to write it as a r function.

The following code is to replace a missing value by its last value using a loop. Can someone tell me how to revise the code.

```
t = data.frame(id = c(1,NA,3,NA,4,NA,NA))    # create data

#function
rretainmissing <- function(data, var){
    for(i in 2:nrow(data)){ # 
        data$var[i] <- ifelse(is.na(data$var[i]), data$var[i-1], data$var[i])
    } #
}

t1 = rretainmissing(data = t, var = id)    # use function to create new data
```

Comment: See `tidyr::fill` or `zoo::na.locf`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion for tidyr package, but I still want to know what's wrong in my function and how to revise to.

Comment: Also if `data` has 1 row your loop will take `for i in 2:1`, and if it has 0 rows 2:0. Use `for i in seq_len(nrow(data))` for safety and skip the first case, or check that the number of rows will be larger or equal than two before the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already functions that do this efficiently, namely `tidyr::fill` and `zoo::na.locf`, but to fix what you've got, you need to pass the column name as a string, subset accordingly, and make sure your function returns the data after the loop:

```r
t = data.frame(id = c(1,NA,3,NA,4,NA,NA))    # create data

#function
rretainmissing <- function(data, var){
    for(i in 2:nrow(data)){ 
        # this is assigning to a copy of the data in the function's environment...
        data[[var]][i] <- ifelse(is.na(data[[var]][i]), data[[var]][i-1], data[[var]][i])
    }
    data    # ...so return it at the end
}

rretainmissing(data = t, var = 'id')
#>   id
#> 1  1
#> 2  1
#> 3  3
#> 4  3
#> 5  4
#> 6  4
#> 7  4
```

Note you can use `data[i, var]` form, but the double-bracket form is safer instead of relying on `drop = TRUE`. You can also work with unevaluated column names instead of strings, but that's more work.

Answer (score 0):

We can create a function with `Rcpp`.  The below code is saved as `replacena.cpp`

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

//[[Rcpp::export]]

NumericVector replace_na_prev(NumericVector x) {

    int n = x.size();
    LogicalVector lv = is_na(x);

    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if ((lv[i] == TRUE) & (lv[i-1] != TRUE)) {
            x[i] = x[i-1];

        }


    }
    return x;
}
```

and called with `sourceCpp` in `R`

```
library(Rcpp)
sourceCpp("replacena.cpp")
df$id <- replace_na_prev(df$id)
df$id
#[1] 1 1 3 3 4 4 4
```

---

Or can use `na.locf` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(df)
#  id
#1  1
#2  1
#3  3
#4  3
#5  4
#6  4
#7  4
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,NA,3,NA,4,NA,NA))
```